# What causes an EC2 instance to stop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I suddenly started having issues connecting to my EC2 instance, and in the AWS console, I noticed the instance status was `stopped`.

I am not very familiar with AWS EC2, but if I understand correctly, EC2 instances don't stop on their own, so I must have triggered it somehow. How could this happen? Could it have errored out somehow, or did someone have to explicitly stop it?

Comment: Go to CloudTrial Event history, and search for events related to stopping the instance. This will allow you to identify when and who/what stopped the instance.

Comment: Did you create an Auto Scaling group? Instances do not stop unless they are commanded to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AWS** doesn't take any action by own; there might a possibility you have triggered it by mistake. Since you can start it again also you can set one **cloudwatch** alarm to get more notification about the running Instance.

At the same time, you can create one topic for **SNS** and subscribe to it via email. so that if anything happens with your instance it will notify you or you can set the action for all the available events